# Upload large base64 string

Tags: android, okhttp, android-bitmap, multipartentity, image-conversion

I need to upload base 64 string to server. String length is too large approximately 5.6 million characters(only one string at a time). For this, which is the best/fastest way to send the string to server? I found many solutions, but commonly used are MultipartEntityBuilder Class and okhttp library. If I use any one of these, is there any image size limitation?

Comment: base 64 causes this issue many times, you should use Multipart instead

Comment: Thank you for help

Comment: hi vivek can you give sample code of multipart request in android